# php - finding value from array in a string and extract substring containing that value

Tags: php

I would like to extract names from string consisting of `name (some title), address (may contain commas)`

Examples:

```
John Doe PhD., 25 Oak Rd, Ridgeville, WA, USA
Peter Smith PhD. and Hannah Smith, 55 Riverside Ave, Alice Springs, NT, Australia
John Miles, BA, PhD., 152 Rain Rd, Copper Mines, Canada
Cool Company, Inc., 152 Great Rd, NZ
```

Say that each of these lines is stored in variable `$string`.

Expected output:

```
John Doe PhD.
Peter Smith PhD. and Hannah Smith
John Miles, BA, PhD.
Cool Company, Inc.
```

What I did - I prepared an array of titles

```
$titles = array("PhD.", "MA", "MSc", "BA", "Inc.");
```

and want to search through `$string` for any of `$titles`.

The issue is that I need to find the last title in the string (so some kind of backwards search) and then extract the substring containing that title (plus everything from the beginning of the string) - while doing that, not to end until the next comma (see line 2 - couples) so I have the whole name (names in case of couples).

Comment: can you share the expected output with respect to those strings ??

Comment: we can split each string by `,` into an array , Then loop through the array to see if we can find the title in the sub strings .  If found then get the same string. But if you got these kind of strings in large, then it will be sort of performance issue.

Comment: @Sameer K I already did that, does not provide a solution since it does not allow me to easily find the last title and as you see, names can contain commas inside, so splitting them by `,` is not providing a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, This might help you. Try below code. I have tried the code in comments.

```
$str = "Peter Smith PhD. and Hannah Smith, 55 Riverside Ave, Alice Springs, NT, Australia";
$substring = getSubstring($str);
echo $substring;
function getSubString($str) {

  $titles = array("PhD.", "MA", "MSc", "BA", "Inc.");
  foreach ($titles as $key => $val) {

    //Search for title in string
    if(strpos($str, $val)) {

        //if found then find the first occurance of the title in string in reverse
        $lastTitlePosition = strrpos($str, $val, 0);

        //then find the next comma after title
        $commaPositionAfterTitle = strpos($str, ',', $lastTitlePosition);

        //then return substring till that comma of substring where title found
        return  substr($str,0,$commaPositionAfterTitle );
    } else {
        return "not found";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to echo the `$substring`, updated my code. Check now.

Comment: it seems that (i) the function stops when the first title is not found; and (ii) if found a title, does not test whether that is the last title (there later may be a title divided by comma) - see http://ideone.com/LHFcJ7

Comment: I edited your answer to contain a working solution and dealing with (i) and (ii) above